# How can I select different websites from a table?

Tags: swift, webview, tableview

I'm working on a sort of bonus challenge with Project 4 from Hacking With Swift, and I'm not sure how to select a different websites from a table view. I have a table view that goes to a detail view with a web view, but I'm not sure where to go from here.

my view controller

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UITableViewController {

var websites = ["apple.com", "hackingwithswift.com"]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    //THIS DISPLAYS THE WEBSITE NAMES IN THE TABLE ROWS
    return websites.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Website", for: indexPath)
    //THIS DISPLAYS A WEBSITE NAME IN EACH CELL
    cell.textLabel?.text = websites[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Detail") as? DetailViewController {
        vc.selectedWebsite = websites[indexPath.row]
        //THIS PIECE BELOW LOADS ANIMATES THE NEW VIEW CONTROLLER
        navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    }
}
```

}

and my detail view controller

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class DetailViewController: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate {

var selectedWebsite: String?
var webView: WKWebView!

override func loadView() {
    webView = WKWebView()
    webView.navigationDelegate = self
    view = webView
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    let url = URL(string: "https://www.hackingwithswift.com")!
    webView.load(URLRequest(url: url))
    webView.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = true
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


/*
// MARK: - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/

}
```

Thanks in advance for any ideas. I'm new to this and feel clueless as to what to do.

Answer (score 1):

Just pass the selected url to `URL` in your DetailViewController `viewDidLoad()`

```
let url = URL(string: selectedWebsite!)!
```

Comment: Where should I then store my URLs?